# Should character descriptions be written in past or present tense?

Tags: characters, description, tenses

My novel is written in past tense and I'm wondering if the description of my characters should be written in present or in past too, especially if my characters are part of a series and will be appearing throughout future books.

Should it be:

> ... Blue pupils adorn her...

Or:

> ... Blue pupils adorned her...

Comment: Definitely past tense. Present tense is tricky anyway, but also doesn't sound/feel right.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, you should not mix tenses. If the rest of your book is in past tense, your character descriptions should also be in past tense. The fact that your novel will be part of a series doesn't change that. So for your example, you would write, "Blue pupils adorned her..."